# Begin equation numbering with specific number

Tags: numbering, counters

I would like to start my equations numbering with 
`(8.67)`, so I used `\setcounter{chapter}{7}` but using `\setcounter{equation}{66}` does not help. How can I start equations numbering within chapter from number different than `1`?

Here is more code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, c5paper]{book}
\usepackage{latexsym}%symbole do \LaTeXe
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\setcounter{equation}{66}

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\frac{i_{k}}{i_{p}}=\frac{1}{1,02+0471\surd\bar{a}/K\surd\bar{l}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does *not help* help mean? What is the result? `\setcounter{chapter}{8}` and `\setcounter{equation}{66}` works for me

Comment: It means that I still get ``(8.1)`` instead of ``(8.67)``.

Comment: Show us more of your code then -- are you using `\setcounter{chapter}{7}` before `\chapter{foo}` and `\setcounter{equation}{66}` as well?

Comment: I get `(7.67)`, which is expected since `chapter` has the value of 7 then

Comment: Recall that the `\chapter` command resets `equation`, so you have to say `\setcounter{equation}{66}` *after* issuing `\chapter`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work: `\setcounter{equation}{66}` after `\chapter{...}` since `\chapter` usually resets the equation counter.

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\chapter{foo}   % chapter steps to 8 and resets equation to 1

\setcounter{equation}{66}
\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Setting `\setcounter{chapter}{8}` and omitting `\chapter{foo}` works too...